# Axios, api ,laravel get :get method is working.. but for post method cors error

Tags: php, api, axios, laravel-5.5

Working with axios. my get method is working, but post method show an cors error. and get different header response in chome->networs->header

```
axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login', {
            params : {

                username:username,
                password:password,
            }
            })
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log(response)
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error)
            })
```

Header response  for get

```
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin    *
  Access-Control-Allow-Methods POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
   Access-Control-Allow-Headers 
   Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin
```

header response for post

```
    Allow       POST
     Access-Control-Request-Method      POST
    Access-Control-Request-Headers      content-type
```

help me plz.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will get same issue

And i trying [this url](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) and solve my problem

*please try this....*